# cmake string begins with a caret(^) and ends with a dollar sign($)?

Tags: makefile, cmake

I saw a strange cmake line that contains a tring begins with "^" and ends with "$". However, it is not a regular expression, but rather a if statement. It's like this:

```
  if ("^${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}$" STREQUAL "^${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}$")
```

Can you tell what does this means? Is it necessary to add the caret and dollar sign to compare the two strings?

Thanks at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no reason in such string "wrapping" when compare *quoted* values.

Some languages (e.g. bash) have some problem when compare *possibly-empty* values, so adding a symbol to both sides of comparison have a sense. But again, CMake has no such problem if argument is quoted.

This is valid:

```
if("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" STREQUAL "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
```

Moreover, taking into account **nature of given variables**:

- after `project()` call both variables exists,
- variables are non-empty
- variables contain paths, which very unlikely has a `;` symbol,

omitting quotes would also be valid in most cases:

```
if(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} STREQUAL ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Finally, the most natural way for compare strings in CMake:

```
if(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR)
```

In this case, CMake automatically attempts to dereference variables with unquoted names.